# We assume that there exists a ring homomorphism $f:k[x,y]/(\phi(x,y))\to k[t]/(t^2)$ that satisfy given conditions.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $k$ be a field, $r \in k$, and $\phi(x,y)=\sum a_{ij}x^iy^j\in k[x,y]$. We assume that there exists a ring homomorphism
$$f:k[x,y]/(\phi(x,y))\to k[t]/(t^2)$$
satisfying: $f(a+(\phi(x,y)))=a+(t^2)$ for any $a \in k$; $f(x+(\phi(x,y)))=t+(t^2)$;
and $f(y+(\phi(x,y)))=r\cdot t+(t^2)$.

My questions are as follows:

> (1) Find conditions of $r$ and $a_{ij}$.

It's easily seen that $(y-rx)+(\phi)\in \ker f$. Let $p(x,y)+(\phi) \in \ker f$. Divide as polynomials of $y$
$p(x,y)=(y-rx)q(x,y)+h(x)$ then $h(x)\in \ker f$ i.e. $h(t)=0$. Hence $h=0$.
We have $\ker f =(y-rx)+(\phi)$. To find a necessary condition for $r$ and $a_{ij}$, I calculate
$0=f(\phi)=\sum f(a_{ij})f(x)^if(y)^j=\sum a_{ij}r^jt^{i+j} +(t^2)$.
This means that, $a_{00}=0$ and $a_{ij}r=0$ for all $i+j>0$. Is this a sufficient condition for $r$ and $a_{ij}$?

> (2) If there uniquely exists $r$ for $\phi(x,y)$, describe $r$ by means of $a_{ij}$.

I could not figure out how important the uniqueness of $r$ is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, we have a $K$-homomorphism $f:K[X,Y]\to K[T]/(T^2)$ given by $f(X)=t$ and $f(Y)=rt$ (here $t$ denotes the residue class of $T$ modulo $(T^2)$), and want to find out when $p(X,Y)\in\ker f$. This is equivalent to $p(t,rt)=0$, that is, $p(T,rT)\in(T^2)$. But $$p(X,Y)=a_{00}+a_{10}X+a_{01}Y+\text{terms of degree $\ge 2$}$$ and then $$p(T,rT)=a_{00}+a_{10}T+a_{01}rT+\cdots\in(T^2)\iff a_{00}=0\text{ and }a_{10}+a_{01}r=0.$$

This is also equivalent to $p\in(Y-rX,X^2)$, that is, $\ker f=(Y-rX,X^2)$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\ker f=(Y-rX) \iff$ $a_{00}=0$ and $a_{10}+a_{01}r=0$?

Comment: @user Actually $\ker f=(Y-rX,X^2)$. (I have edited the answer.)

Comment: Thanks. I understood your proof. But I am still confused in understanding the question. I know that we should find "something $\iff $ constrains on $r$ and $a_{ij}$". What "something" really is? According to your edited post, the "something" should be $p \in \ker f$. It isn't clear to me why $\ker f$ comes into picture.

Comment: @user The given homomorphism should be well defined, that is, if two polynomials $p,q$ are such that $p=q$ modulo $(\phi)$ then their images by $f$ must be equal, that is, $f(p)=f(q)$. But $p=q$ modulo $(\phi)$ iff $p-q\in(\phi)$ and $f(p)=f(q)$ iff $p-q\in\ker f$. In particular, for $p=\phi$ and $q=0$ we get the condition $\phi\in\ker f$.

Comment: Now I fully understand yours. Thanks so much.